# Shrine gem - how to delete uploaded images from s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shrine

Apparently `:remove_attachment` plugin does the trick with checking and submitting but how can I call the method from the controller?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All plugins which allow you to set up form fields (`remove_attachment`, `remote_url`, `data_uri`, ...) work in a way that they add getters and setters to your models, so if you have a Photo model with "image" attachment, you can do `photo.remove_image = true`.

However, for removing attachments in Ruby code you don't need the `remove_attachment` plugin, you can just assign the attachment to `nil`:

```
photo.image = nil
# or
photo.update(image: nil)
```

Comment: I got it now. Just deleting a record from your database table with image_data column deletes the image from s3 as well. Thanks.